# Quickbook Create invoice error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

i am getting this error when i am creating invoice using Quickbook rails gem (quickbooks-ruby)

```
Quickbooks::IntuitRequestException (Required param missing, need to supply the required value for the API:
    Required parameter Line.DetailType is missing in the request):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:42:in `oauth_callback'
```

**My Controller**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        upload_service = Quickbooks::Service::Upload.new
        # result = upload_service.upload("tmp/monkey.jpg", "image/jpeg", attachable_metadata)
      end

      def authenticate
        callback = users_oauth_callback_url
        token = QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callback)
        session[:qb_request_token] = Marshal.dump(token)
        redirect_to("https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token=#{token.token}") and return
      end

      def oauth_callback
        at = Marshal.load(session[:qb_request_token]).get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
        session[:token] = at.token
        session[:secret] = at.secret
        session[:realm_id] = params['realmId']
     end

     def create_invoice
        access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER, session[:token], session[:secret] )
        invoice = Quickbooks::Model::Invoice.new
        invoice.customer_id = 123
        invoice.txn_date = Date.civil(2013, 11, 20)
        invoice.doc_number = "1001" # my custom Invoice # - can leave blank to have Intuit auto-generate it
        line_item = Quickbooks::Model::InvoiceLineItem.new
        line_item.amount = 50
        line_item.description = "Plush Baby Doll"
        line_item.sales_item! do |detail|
          detail.unit_price = 50
          detail.quantity = 1
          detail.item_id = 500 # Item ID here
        end

        invoice.line_items << line_item
        service = Quickbooks::Service::Invoice.new
        service.company_id = session[:realm_id]
        service.access_token = access_token
        created_invoice = service.create(invoice)
        puts created_invoice.id
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

**config/initializers/quickeebooks.rb**

```
OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

::QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER = OAuth::Consumer.new(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, {
    :site                 => "https://oauth.intuit.com",
    :request_token_path   => "/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
    :authorize_url        => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
    :access_token_path    => "/oauth/v1/get_access_token"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

> Required parameter Line.DetailType is missing in the reques

Did you specify `DetailType` in your request. It doesn't look like it:

```
    line_item = Quickbooks::Model::InvoiceLineItem.new
    line_item.amount = 50
    line_item.description = "Plush Baby Doll"
```

Refer to the documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/invoice

Which indicates:

```
DetailType:
*required*
LineDetailTypeEnum 
Set to SalesItemLineDetail for this type of line.
```

Comment: thanks, but i am make some small mistake that's why the error comes.